# How to use post_save signal with custom user model extended with AbstractBaseUser

Tags: django, django-models, django-signals, django-custom-user

There are two apps in my ecommerce website and i have been following a particular tutorial on youtube. In the course, the guy used django-allauth package for login purposes. I followed the course along but I created custom user model exending AbstracBaseUser class in **account** app.

I created another app called **product** where I handled all the ecommerce logics.

Here's the code:

**models.py** (account)

```
class MyAccountManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, username, first_name, last_name, gstin_no, phone_no, password=None):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError("Users must have an email address")
        if not username:
            raise ValueError("Users must have a username")
        if not first_name:
            raise ValueError("Users must have First Name")
        if not last_name:
            raise ValueError("Users must have Last Name")
        if not gstin_no:
            raise ValueError("Users must have a valid GSTIN Number")
        if not phone_no:
            raise ValueError("Users must have a valid Phone Number")

        user = self.model(
                email=self.normalize_email(email),
                username=username,
                first_name=first_name,
                last_name=last_name,
                gstin_no=gstin_no,
                phone_no=phone_no,
            )
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, username, first_name, last_name, gstin_no, phone_no, password):
        user = self.create_user(
                email=self.normalize_email(email),
                password=password,
                username=username,
                first_name=first_name,
                last_name=last_name,
                gstin_no=gstin_no,
                phone_no=phone_no,
            )
        user.is_admin = True
        user.is_staff = True
        user.is_superuser = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

class Account(AbstractBaseUser):
    email               = models.EmailField(verbose_name="email", max_length=60, unique=True)
    username            = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
    date_joined         = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='date joined', auto_now_add=True)
    last_login          = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='last login', auto_now=True)
    is_admin            = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active           = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff            = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser        = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    first_name          = models.CharField(verbose_name="first name", max_length=20)
    last_name           = models.CharField(verbose_name="last name", max_length=20)
    gstin_no            = models.CharField(verbose_name='gstin no', max_length=15, unique=True)
    phone_no            = models.BigIntegerField(unique=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'gstin_no', 'phone_no', ]

    objects = MyAccountManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return self.is_admin

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return True
```

**models.py** (product)

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    stripe_customer_id = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    one_click_purchasing = models.BooleanField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

def userprofile_receiver(sender, instance, created, *args, **kwargs):
    if created:
        userprofile = UserProfile.objects.create(user=instance)

post_save.connect(userprofile_receiver, sender=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
```

**views.py** (product)

```
class PaymentView(LoginRequiredMixin, View):
    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        order = Order.objects.get(user=self.request.user, ordered=False)
        if order.billing_address:
            context = {
                'order': order,
                'DISPLAY_COUPON_FORM': False
            }
            userprofile = self.request.user.userprofile
            if userprofile.one_click_purchasing:
                #fetch the user's card list
                cards = stripe.Customer.list_sources(
                    userprofile.stripe_customer_id,
                    limit = 3,
                    object = 'card'
                )
                card_list = cards['data']
                if len(card_list) > 0:
                    # update the card with the default card
                    context.update({
                        'card': card_list[0]
                    })
            return render(self.request, 'product/payment.html', context)
        else:
            messages.warning(self.request, "You have not added a billing address.")
            return redirect("checkout")
```

The error I am getting is:
[RelatedObjectDoesNotExist at /payment/stripe/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vi4mZ.png)
Account has no userprofile.

How can I get this working. I am not able to get the concept here about what's wrong.

Answer (score -1):

Go to django admin and check is that userprofile created for that user.If not,  Then it is possible you have added user before adding this signal functionality. create new user and check userprofile. If still not created.  There is something wrong with your signal.